# Load File to csv file from desktop to Mainframe flat file

Tags: mainframe, rexx

I have requirement like, i need to load the csv file to the mainframe flat file.
here is what i thought till now
1-we will create on file in that we can update the desktop csv file path
2-rexx will check this path and load the csv ile to mainframe pds.

I am looking -how can i load the csv file to  mainframe using REXX...?

Thanks,
Akki

Comment: Are you running Rexx on the PC or on the Mainframe? And what OS are your running (mainframe and PC)?

Comment: Are you just wanting to upload the CSV to a dataset? Need more information.

Answer (score 0):

Like the others, I'm not quite sure what you are wanting to do. Is it that you want to transfer a .csv file from a PC to a mainframe PDS member? And then? Do you want to parse the uploaded .csv file?

I can say that at least one thing will happen - the .csv file is likely in ASCII format and when it is transferred to the mainframe it is usually automatically converted to EBCDIC format. Again, I'm not entirely clear on your other requirements.